# Communicate with a docker container from another docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

This is my docker-compose file.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  foo01:
    shm_size: "1000000000"
    build:
      context: ./foo
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - "./foo/src:/tmp/"
  foo02:
    shm_size: "1000000000"
    build:
      context: ./foo
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - "./foo/src:/tmp/"
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    tty: true
    links:
      - foo01
      - foo02
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

And this is my nginx conf file if it's needed.

```
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

 proxy_headers_hash_max_size 1024;
 proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 64;

 upstream TestApp {
    # References to our app containers, via docker compose
    server foo01:5000;
    server foo02:5000;
 }

 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
      #   proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffers 8 24k;
        proxy_buffer_size 4k;
        proxy_pass http://TestApp;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
  }
}
```

My question is, once I build and run docker-compose, how do I check if foo01:5000 is reachable from my nginx docker container? Is it possible to communicate from the bash shell of a docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could open the bash of a docker container as fallow

```
docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> bash
```

And execute a curl command to other container, if you have curl in your container, otherwise you have to install it

```
curl foo01:5000
```

But I think the problem is in the docker-compose.yml file, you didn't specified the port 5000 for foo01 and expose it.

Comment: I used curl foo01:5000 and I am getting an html response (the html from foo01). So, that means its reachable, right? Sorry but I am new to this. :)

Comment: Yeas, it's reachable from nginx container if you get a response